# Segmentation Fault Issues in Game of Life Implementation

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, mpi

For a project in my Parallel Computing class, I need to implement a parallel version of the Game of Life.

I am using a function written by my textbook's author called "read_row_stripped_matrix". This function reads in input from a file that contains the number of rows in the matrix, number of columns in the matrix, and the data in the matrix.

The function sets up the two dimensional matrix by allocating a one dimensional array called "storage", which holds all of the matrix's data. Each row of the two dimensional matrix points to its first element within storage, like in this picture:

[image]

We are required to clean up the function code so that it fits with our C style guide. So I cleaned a few things up so it would be more readable.

The issue I'm running into now occurs with pointing each row in the matrix to its first element in storage. I'm getting a segmentation fault while hooking up these pointers, specifically in this section of the function:

```
   /* Dynamically allocate matrix. Allow double subscripting
      through 'a'. */

   *storage = my_malloc (id, local_rows * *n * sizeof(int));       
   *subs    = my_malloc (id, local_rows * PTR_SIZE);

   for (i = 0; i < local_rows; i++) {
      *subs[i]=&(*storage[i * *n]);
   }
```

What's puzzling me is that I'm pretty sure I've allocated enough memory for the array. In the example I'm testing, *m and *n equal 5, and local_rows equals 5. So I'm allocating 25*sizeof(int) for storage which should be sufficient to hold all elements for a 5x5 matrix.

This is the my_malloc function, which mallocs for a specific processor:

```
/*
 *   Function 'my_malloc' is called when a process wants
 *   to allocate some space from the heap. If the memory
 *   allocation fails, the process prints an error message
 *   and then aborts execution of the program.
 */

void* my_malloc (
   int id,     /* IN - Process rank */
   int bytes)  /* IN - Bytes to allocate */
{
   void *buffer;
   if ((buffer = malloc ((size_t) bytes)) == NULL) {
      printf ("Error: Malloc failed for process %d\n", id);
      fflush (stdout);
      MPI_Abort (MPI_COMM_WORLD, MALLOC_ERROR);
   }
   return buffer;
}
```

I honestly find pointers confusing, so forgive me if the issue is obvious. I have been working on this for longer than I should so my brain is probably fried.

If you need more code, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Please read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sorry about that, I'll edit this and make it more readable.

Comment: Okay, I think this is a bit better.

Comment: Did you follow the link, or just read the title? And did the code work before you "cleaned things up"? And is it the *reading* or the *writing* that causes the segmentation fault?

Comment: Yes, I did follow the link. And no it didn't work before cleaning things up, because the author was using "fread", which fails to read in integers properly from an ASCII file. The "cleaning up" that I did was adding braces  to make it more readable, and using fscanf instead of fread. Finally, I'm not completely sure but I believe it is the writing that's causing the segmentation fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you do this:

```
*subs    = my_malloc (id, local_rows * PTR_SIZE);
```

Then, you do this:

```
*subs[i]=&(*storage[i * *n]);
```

Pretty sure that's your problem, right there. Looks to me like it should really be:

```
(*subs)[i]=&(*storage[i * *n]);
```

Comment: probably `(*storage)[i * *n]` also

Comment: Yup. That too. Seems obvious.

Comment: Okay, I will try that out. But why do you put the parentheses around *subs out of curiosity? Thanks for your help.